# How to avoid rendering the group connection when the bot replies to it on the client side

Tags: php-telegram-bot

How can the group address output by the robot not be parsed in the client (in the picture below, the title avatar and group description are automatically parsed and rendered)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mWup.png)

Hope normal output
There is no need for the telegram client to automatically parse the title description and avatar of the first line.